# Differences between ampersand (&) and dot (.) while invoking a PowerShell scriptblock

Tags: powershell, ampersand

I would like to understand the difference between invoking a PowerShell scriptblock with an ampersand (&) versus doing so using a dot (.).

For example, if I have a scriptblock like so:

```
$scriptBlock = { Write-Host -Object "Hello, $message" }
```

and we invoke it using an ampersand (&) operator like so:

```
$message = "World"
& $scriptBlock
```

the output is:

```
Hello, World
```

Invoking the same scriptblock with a dot (.) operator also gives the exact same output.

```
$message = "World"
. &scriptBlock
```

I would like to know if there are any differences in these two approaches.

Comment: `&` executes the command in a new scope, `.` executes the command in the callers scope. Change your scriptblock to `{$var = 123}` and then see if `$var` has a value after running with `&` vs with `.`

Comment: Did you read _basic_ [About Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) article (or at least `Get-Help 'about_Operators' -ShowWindow`)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `.` not necessary use caller scope. If command bounded to different `SessionState`, then command always jump here: `$a=1; New-Module { $a=10; function f { ($a=$a+1) } } | Out-Null; f; f; f; . f; . f; . f; $a`. As you can see, caller scope `$a` are not affected by `. f`.