# What is the difference between dot (.) and ampersand (&) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, what is the difference between using dot (`.`) and ampersand (`&`) when invoking a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program?

For example:

```
. foo.sh1
& foo.sh1
```

---

There is a very similar question which has been incorrectly closed as a duplicate: [Differences between ampersand (&) and dot (.) while invoking a PowerShell scriptblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331465/differences-between-ampersand-and-dot-while-invoking-a-powershell-script). The questions are different and have completely different keywords and search rankings. The answer on [What is the `.` shorthand for in a PowerShell pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855549/what-is-the-shorthand-for-in-powershell-pipeline) only answers half the question.

Comment: Have you read and compared the relevant documentation sections([Call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) and [Dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-))?  Is the information there inadequate for answering your question and, if so, how?

Comment: @BACON: Thanks for providing the doc links. As is - sadly - typical, the official documentation doesn't tell the full story.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- The **difference between the `.` and `&` operators matters *only* when calling PowerShell *scripts* or *functions*** (or their aliases) - for *cmdlets* and *external programs*, they act the same.
- For scripts and functions, **`.` and `&` differ with respect to *scoping* of the definition of *functions*, *aliases*, and *variables***:

  - **[`&`, the *call operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-)**, executes scripts and functions in a ***child* scope**, which is the ***typical* use case**: functions and scripts are typically expected to **execute *without side effects***:

    - The variables, (nested) functions, aliases defined in the script / function invoked are local to the invocation and go out of scope when the script exits / function returns.
    - Note, however, that **even a script run in a *child* scope can - by explicit action - affect the caller's environment**, such as by using `Set-Location` to change the current location, explicitly modifying the parent scope (`Set-Variable -Scope 1 ...`) or the global scope (`$global:...`) or defining process-level [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables).
  - **[`.`, the *dot-sourcing operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)**, executes scripts and functions in the ***current* scope** and is **typically used to *modify the caller's scope* by adding functions, aliases, and possibly variables *for later use***. For instance, this mechanism is used to load the `$PROFILE` file that initializes an interactive session.

The caveat is that for *functions* (as opposed to scripts) the reference scope for *child* vs. *current* is not necessarily the *caller's* scope: if the function was defined in a *module*, the reference scope is *that module's scope domain*:

- In other words: trying to use `.` with a *module-originated* function is virtually pointless, because the scope getting modified is the *module's*.
- That said, functions defined in modules aren't usually designed with dot-sourcing in mind anyway.

Comment: I'm writing a module and I want a `Use-*` command that can modify variables in the caller's scope, eg `Use-Context $context { $a = 'a' }` should set $a in the caller's scope. In my Pester tests, this is working despite Use-Context being a function defined in a module. I can also use `icm -nonewscope`. Which should I be using here, if either, and why does this seem to contradict what you're saying about module scope?

Comment: @Stroniax, script blocks (`{ ... }`)  run in the scope in which they are _defined_, even if invoked from a function defined in a module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327851/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can also run things inside a module scope with the call operator, from my notes from Windows Powershell in Action.

```
# get and variable in module scope
$m = get-module counter
& $m Get-Variable count
& $m Set-Variable count 33

# see func def
& $m Get-Item function:Get-Count

# redefine func in memory
& $m {
  function script:Get-Count
  {
    return $script:count += $increment * 2
  }
}

# get original func def on disk
Import-Module .\counter.psm1 -Force
```

A few other things:

```
# run with commandinfo object
$d = get-command get-date
& $d

# call anonymous function
& {param($x,$y) $x+$y} 2 5

# same with dot operator
. {param($x,$y) $x+$y} 2 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Mathias mentioned as a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331465/differences-between-ampersand-and-dot-while-invoking-a-powershell-script) thread. `&` is used to invoke the expression whatever comes after the `&` and `.` is used to invoke it in the current scope and is normally used to dot source a helper file which contains functions to make it available in callers scope.

- See https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/02/02/exploring-dot-sourcing-in-powershell.aspx for more dot sourcing.

Answer (score 0):

To segregate and give a clear understanding, I am explaining a scenario. 
Imagine you have function named `MyFunction` in a `source.ps1`. And you wish to use that function in another script(*MyCustomScript.ps1*)

Put a line in MyCustomScript.ps1 like the below and you should be able to use it.

```
. path\of\the\source.ps1 

MyFunction
```

So you are using the function which is present in source.ps1 in your custom script. 
Whereas, `&` is the call operator in Powershell which will help you to call any of the outside executable like `psexec` and others.

Invoking a command (either directly or with the call operator) will create another scope known as child scope and will be gone once the command been executed. If the command is changing any of the values in a global variable then in that case the changes will be lost when the scope ends as well.

To avoid this drawback and to keep any changes made to global variables you can `dot` the script which will always execute the script in your current scope.

Dot sourcing will only run the function or script within the current scope and call operator (`&`) which will run a function or script as usual; but it will never add to the current scope.

Hope this gives an idea on when to use what.