# Why does the dot source operator convert strings into commands

Tags: windows, powershell, obfuscation, malware

I came across a script that obfuscated its calls using the [dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-).

`$ORMEFyak=.('n'+'ew-obje'+'ct') NeT.WebcLIENt;`

This seems to be equivalent to:
`$var = New-Object Net.WebClient`

Running `. "help"` returns the contents of the `help` cmdlet.

Why exactly does the dot source operator act like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is not specific to `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-); it equally applies to `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

- Only when you're invoking a *script file* (`*.ps1`) (or, less commonly, *function* or *script block*) do `.` and `&` behave differently: `.` runs the code *directly in the caller's scope*, whereas `&`, which is more typical, runs it in a *child scope* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680512/45375) for more information.
- In the case of [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object), as a *cmdlet*, you can technically use them interchangeably (or omit them altogether - see below), but for conceptual clarity it's better to use `&` unless actual dot-sourcing is required.

**It isn't so much that they *convert* a string to a command, it is that their purpose is to *execute* a command given by its *name***, as a *string*, among other forms (see below).

**The *specific syntax* used to provide or construct this name for `.` or `&` is *incidental***, and in your case a string-concatenation expression was used to obscure the name of the command being invoked.

- However, specifying the name of a command *unquoted, verbatim* (if syntactically possible) is special in that you can then invoke *without an operator* - `&` is then *implied*; see below for an example.

Therefore, all of the following variations are equivalent (for the reasons stated above, I'm using `&`):

```sh
# Bareword (unquoted, verbatim) command name
# If you don't need dot-sourcing, you can invoke *as-is* - 
# use of & is implied.
New-Object regex 'foo?'

# Optionally, use &
& New-Object regex 'foo?'

# If the command name *needs quoting*, is *(based on) a variable* or
# *built by an expression*, & is *required*
$cmd = 'New-Object'
& $cmd regex 'foo?'

& ('New-' + 'Object') regex 'foo?'
```

Note that in addition to acting on command *names* (strings), `.` and `&` can also invoke [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (e.g. `& { New-Object regex 'foo?' }`) and command-*information* objects returned by [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) (e.g., `& (Get-Command New-Object) regex 'foo?'`)