# Use Powershell console to run a script from a different folder

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that takes two arguments.

```
param([string]$folder, [string]$filename)
```

When I open a Powershell shell, navigate to the folder that contains the script, and run it from there, the script is executed correctly:

```
C:\scriptfolder> ".\script.ps1" "C:\folder for argument" "filename.ext"
```

When I try to run the script from a different folder, I get an error message:

```
C:\otherfolder> "C:\scriptfolder\script.ps1" "C:\folder for argument" "filename.ext"
```

> At line:1 char:nn
>
> Unexpected token '"C:\folder for argument"' in expression or statement.

How can I run this script from another folder?

Comment: You need to dot-source the path to the ps1 file `. "C:\scriptfolder\script.ps1" "C:\folder for argument" "filename.ext"` or use the `&` call operator

Comment: That works, so I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to leave this question as 'Unanswered', here my comment as answer

There are two ways to do what you want. The first is by using [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
. "C:\scriptfolder\script.ps1" "C:\folder for argument" "filename.ext"
```

The second method would be by using the [`& call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#call-operator-)

```
& "C:\scriptfolder\script.ps1" "C:\folder for argument" "filename.ext"
```

The difference between the two methods is that a script that is invoked using dot-sourcing runs in the **current** scope, while with the second method, using the call operator, scripts and functions run in a **child** scope.

You can find an excellent explanation in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680512/9898643)