# PowerShell not reloading when running & $profile

Tags: powershell, function, profile

First post in Stack Overflow so bear with me...

I update my profile to create/adjust custom functions as I complete my day-day work. After saving the edits to my profile, the new/updated function isn't working according to the new profile after running `& $profile` in my current PowerShell session. It only works after closing my current session and reopening a new PowerShell instance. I am using PowerShell 7.3.5 and Windows Terminal.

For example....

In my profile I have a few custom functions to open the last X number of files downloaded to my Downloads folder. Running this command `open_dnld` with no input will start the last file in this folder. Running this command with an input of 2 `open_dnld(2)` starts the process for my last 2 files. Below is the function definition:

Old Function:

```
Function open_dnld  ([Int16] $NumFiles = 1) {foreach($file in Get-ChildItem ~/Downloads
                                             | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
                                             | Select-Object -First $NumFiles){
      Start-Process $file
  }
}
```

For a test, I just updated the function with $NumFiles having a default value of 2 shown below. After running `& $profile` and thereafter `open_dnld(2)` the function works according to the previous definition and only opens 1 file. But, when I close my current terminal session, open a new instance of PowerShell using Windows Terminal, and then run the command `open_dnld(2)` the function now works according to the new function definition.

Updated Function:

```
Function open_dnld  ([Int16] $NumFiles = 2) {foreach($file in Get-ChildItem ~/Downloads
                                             | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
                                             | Select-Object -First $NumFiles){
      Start-Process $file
  }
}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload a modified [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) you must use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
. $PROFILE
```

By contrast, `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) runs a script in a *child* scope, which means that any aliases, functions, ... it contains are visible to that script only, and go out of scope when the script ends.

In other words: running `& $PROFILE` defeats the very purpose of a profile file: to define aliases, functions, ... in the *caller*'s scope - only `.`  does that.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680512/45375) for details.